# Is processManagement (fork to true) needed when MongoDB is only application running on Linux?

Tags: mongodb, debian-buster

I am having problems logging into the mongo shell when I have configuration file set with processManagement fork set to true. Each time I have fork set to true, I have issues connecting to the mongo shell. Turn fork off (false), I have no issues connecting to the shell. I am using vagrant to build 3 Debian 10 boxes where the only thing I am adding to each box is MongoDB. Each MongoDB box will be a part of a replicaSet and communicate to each other on a private network ip. Do I need to set mongodb to run in the background of a linux OS?  If I do, what is the advantage of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily need to fork/daemonize mongod. For example, this isn't necessary in docker.

For some of the reasons why programs daemonize, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287793/why-do-we-daemonize-processes.